# Confused on DataKinds extension

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds

I learn type programming of Haskell from [Basic Type Level Programming in Haskell](https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2017/04/26/basic_type_level_programming_in_haskell.html) but when it introduce `DataKinds` extension, there are something seems confusing from the example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

Now, `Nat` is promoted to `Kind`, it is okay. But how about `Zero` and `Succ`?

I try to get some information from GHCi, so I type:

```
:kind Zero
```

it gives

```
Zero :: Nat
```

that is okay, `Zero` is a type has kind `Nat`, right? and I try:

```
:type Zero
```

it still gives:

```
Zero :: Nat
```

that means `Zero` has type `Nat`, that is impossible, since `Nat` is a kind not type, right? Does `Nat` is both a type and a kind ??

And other confusing thing is, above blog also mentioned that, when create `Nat` kind, there are two new types: `'Zero` and `'Succ` are created automatically. When I try it from GHCi again:

```
:kind 'Zero
```

gives

```
'Zero :: Nat
```

and

```
:type 'Zero
```

gives

```
 Syntax error on 'Zero
```

Okay, it proves that `'Zero` is a type. but what is the purpose of creating `'Zero` and '`Succ'`??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In unextended Haskell, the declaration

```
data A = B
```

defines two new entities, one each at the computation and type level:

1. At the type level, a new base type named `A` (of kind `*`), and
2. At the computation level, a new base computation named `B` (of type `A`).

When you turn on `DataKinds`, the declaration

```
data A = B
```

now defines four new entities, one at the computation level, two at the type level, and one at the kind level:

1. At the kind level, a new base kind `A`,
2. At the type level, a new base type `'B` (of kind `A`),
3. At the type level, a new base type `A` (of kind `*`), and
4. At the computation level, a new base computation `B` (of type `A`).

This is a strict superset of what we had before: the old (1) is now (3), and the old (2) is now (4).

These new entities explain the following interactions you described:

```
:type Zero
Zero :: Nat
:kind 'Zero
'Zero :: Nat
:type 'Zero
Syntax error on 'Zero
```

I think it's clear how it explains the first two. The last one it explains because `'Zero` is a type-level thing -- you can't ask for the type of a type, only the type of a computation!

Now, in Haskell, every place where a name occurs, it is clear from the surrounding syntax whether that name is intended to be a computation-level name, a type-level name, or a kind-level name. For this reason, it is somewhat annoying to have to include the tick mark in `'B` at the type level -- after all, the compiler *knows* we're at the type level and therefore can't be referring to the unlifted computation-level `B`. So for convenience, you are permitted to leave off the tick mark when that is unambiguous.

From now on, I will distinguish between the "back end" -- where there are only the four entities described above and which are always unambiguous -- and the "surface syntax", which is the stuff you type into a file and pass off to GHC that includes ambiguity but is more convenient. Using this terminology, in the surface syntax, one may write the following things, with the following meanings:

```
Surface syntax    Level           Back end
Name              computation     Name
Name              type            Name if that exists; 'Name otherwise
'Name             type            'Name
Name              kind            Name
---- all other combinations ----  error
```

This explains the first interaction you had (and the only one left unexplained above):

```
:kind Zero
Zero :: Nat
```

Because `:kind` must be applied to a type-level thing, the compiler knows the surface syntax name `Zero` must be a type-level thing. Since there is no type-level back end name `Zero`, it tries `'Zero` instead, and gets a hit.

How can it be ambiguous? Well, notice above that we defined *two* new entities at the type level with one declaration. For simplicity of introduction, I named the new entities on the left- and right-hand side of the equation different things. But let's see what happens if we just tweak the declaration slightly:

```
data A = A
```

We still introduce four new back end entities:

1. Kind `A`,
2. Type `'A` (of kind `A`),
3. Type `A` (of kind `*`), and
4. Computation `A` (of type `A`).

Whoops! There is now both an `'A` and an `A` at the type level. If you leave off the tick mark in the surface syntax, it will use (3), and not (2) -- and you can explicitly choose (2) with the surface syntax `'A`.

What's more, this doesn't have to happen all from a single declaration. One declaration may produce the ticked version and another the non-ticked version; for example

```
data A = B
data C = A
```

will introduce a type-level back end name `A` from the first declaration and a type-level back end name `'A` from the second declaration.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, Does the tricky here is that compiler tries `:kind 'Zero` instead of `:kind Zero` in type-level? Anytime the name `Zero` appear in type-level, compiler replace it with `'Zero`?

Comment: @JoeChoi No, not *any time*, as explained in my answer: the compiler first checks if `Zero` exists, and only if it does not exist will it check whether `'Zero` exists instead.

Comment: @JoeChoi I have added some precision about this question, distinguishing between the back end, where names are always unambiguous, and the surface syntax that we use to communicate with the compiler. See especially the new ASCII-art table that begins "Surface syntax Level Back end". In this terminology, the surface syntax `Zero` may correspond to the back end `Zero` or `'Zero`, depending on what declarations are in scope.

Comment: Thank you very much! it is clear and now I eventually understand why add `data Zero` declaration in leftaroundabout's answer will cause name clashes if doesn't use `'Zeor` instead of `Zero`.

Answer (score 5):

`{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}` does not change what the `data` keyword usually does: it still creates a type `Nat` and two value constructors `Zero` and `Succ`. What this extension does do is, it allows you to use such types as if they were kinds, and values as if they were types.

Thus, if you use `Nat` in a type-level expressions, it'll just use it as a boring Haskell98 type. Only if you use it in an unabiguously *kind*-level expression, do you get the kind version.

This automatic lifting could sometimes cause name clashes, which is, I think, the reason for the `'` syntax:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
data Zero
```

Now, `Zero` by itself is the plain (empty) data type `Zero :: *`, so

```
*Main> :k Zero
Zero :: *
```

In principle, thanks to `DataKinds`, `Zero` is now also a type lifted from the value constructor `Zero :: Nat`, but this is shadowed by the `data Zero`. Thus the quoting-syntax, which always refers to lifted types, never to directly defined ones:

```
*Main> :k 'Zero
'Zero :: Nat
```

Comment: The clash is also particularly evident in `(a,b) :: *` vs `'(a,b) :: (*, *)`. Ditto for `[a] :: *` vs `'[a] :: [*]` (even if these are special syntactic cases).

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank for your answer, Does it mean that when the context need `Nat` as a type then `Nat` is a type and `Zero` and `Succ` are constructor. And when the context need `Nat` as a kind, `Nat` become a kind, and `Zero` and `Succ` become a type? Otherwise, I still don't understand why we need `'Zero`. In what situation the clashes you mentioned in the answer will occur?

Comment: @JoeChoi Yes, everything you asserted is correct. But your question puzzles me; doesn't the answer already give an explicit example where name clashes can occur?

Comment: @DanielWagner I don't understand the example in answer why the name clashes.

Comment: @JoeChoi it clashes because I defined both a data type called `Zero` and a value constructor called `Zero`. In normal Haskell2010, these wouldn't clash because type-level language and value-level language are completely separate, but `-XDataKinds` “copies” the value-level `Zero` into the type-level language, so `Zero` in a type-level context is now ambiguous. To prevent `DataKinds` from breaking any existing code, they made it default to the Haskell2010 meaning, i.e. `Zero :: *`. Thus to also get access to the new meaning of _promoted-to-type value-level constructor_, we need the `'` syntax.

Comment: @JoeChoi I started writing up an explanation of the name clashes, but it turned out to be a bit long for a comment. So I've made an answer with my attempt at a careful explanation of what's going on here.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank for your further explanation, I still unable to comprehend it, maybe I need spend much time to study it.