# What is '[] and ': in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, type-level-computation, data-kinds, heterogeneous-array

I've seen this `'[]` and `':` syntax in a few places, most notably in heterogeneous lists packages like [HList](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HList) or [HVect](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hvect-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-HVect.html).

For example, the heterogeneous vector `HVect` is defined as

```
data HVect (ts :: [*]) where
    HNil :: HVect '[]
    (:&:) :: !t -> !(HVect ts) -> HVect (t ': ts)
```

In GHCi, with extension `TemplateHaskell` or `DataKinds`, I get this

```
> :t '[]
'[] :: template-haskell-2.13.0.0:Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Name
> :t '(:)
'(:) :: template-haskell-2.13.0.0:Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.Name
```

I had the impression that this has to do with dependent types and kinds, etc., not with template haskell.

The search engines, and [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), and [hayoo](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/), handle queries with `'[]` or `':` rather badly, hence the question: **What is the name of these `'[]` and `':` things?** Pointers to documentation or tutorials would be most welcome.

Comment: Data kinds, promoted constructors: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html

Comment: You may also like [Confused on DataKinds extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53815871/791604).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`DataKinds` allows one to use term-level constructors at the type level.

After

```
data T = A | B | C
```

one can write types indexed by a value of `T`

```
data U (t :: T) = ...
foo :: U A -> U B -> ...
```

Here, however, `A` and `B` are used as types, not as values. Hence, they have to be "promoted" using a quote:

```
data U (t :: T) = ...
foo :: U 'A -> U 'B -> ...
```

The same happens with the familiar list syntax. `'[]` is an empty list, promoted at the type level. `'[a,b,c]` is the same as `a ': b ': c ': '[]`, a list promoted at the type level.

```
type           :: kind
'[]            :: [k]   -- polykinded! works for any kind k
'[ 'A, 'B, 'C] :: [T]   -- mind the spaces, we do not want the char '['
'A ': '[]      :: [T]
'[ Int, Bool ] :: [*]   -- a list of types
'[ Int ]       :: [*]   -- a list of types with only one element
[Int]          :: *     -- a type "list of Int"
```

Note the last two cases, where the quote disambiguates the syntax.

Comment: It's also possible to write `' ['A, 'B, 'C]` to disambiguate your example.

Answer (score 2):

The book

***Thinking with Types*** by Sandy Maguire (http://thinkingwithtypes.com)

could be a good resource on topic of type-level programming in Haskell in general.
The chapter "Lifting Restrictions" deals with `DataKinds` and promoted constructors.

(Disclaimer: No affiliation.)