# Why Can't I Construct a Singleton List of Symbol?

Tags: haskell

I'm getting a puzzling error from GHCI, any idea what it means?  A pair of symbols
works just fine, but a singleton list fails.

```
$ ghci
> :m +GHC.Types
> :set -XDataKinds -XKindSignatures
GHC.Types> :kind! (["A", "B"] :: [Symbol])
(["A", "B"] :: [Symbol]) :: [Symbol]
= '["A", "B"]
GHC.Types> :kind! (["A"] :: [Symbol])
<interactive>:1:2: error:
    * Expected kind `[Symbol]', but `["A"]' has kind `*'
    * In the type `(["A"] :: [Symbol])'
<interactive>:1:3: error:
    * Expected a type, but `"A"' has kind `Symbol'
    * In the type `(["A"] :: [Symbol])'
```

Comment: Seems to be a syntax peculiarity. `:kind! ('["A"] :: [Symbol])` works if you use `TypeOperators`. Notice that this is also the case for your first list, so it seems like there is some syntactical sugar (maybe unintended) tol handle this for two or more items.

Comment: Seems to work with a type-level list: `'["A"] :: [Symbol]`. Not posting an answer because I can't provide any sensible explanation of why other cases don't require explicit type-level lists.

Comment: @chepner aha, this is what I needed.

Comment: @chepner `[Int] :: Type` while `'[Int] :: [Type]` -- the notation is ambiguous without the `'`. It is not ambiguous when the list is not a singleton. The notation was invented before `DataKinds`, so at the time no ambiguity arose.

Comment: @chi, I recently learned that you need it for `[]` as well. `[] :: Type -> Type`, while `'[] :: forall k. [k]`.

Comment: @dfeuer Indeed. I included it in my answer below.

Comment: You might also like [Confused on DataKinds extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53812685/791604).

Answer (score 6):

In general, when using "term syntax at the type level" we can find the term notation to be ambiguous in some cases. Hence, when using `DataKinds` GHC requires us to use quotes `'` to disambiguate.

For instance, `(x, y)` is term syntax for a pair. But, alas, `(Bool, Int)` is a type even if it has the same syntax. Indeed, we might well have:

```
(x,y) :: (Bool, Int)       -- term::type
(Bool, Int) :: Type        -- type::kind
```

Now... what if we want to write a pair of types as a "term at the type level"? We want

```
(Bool, Int) :: (Type, Type)  -- term-at-type::kind
-- This is a kind error!
```

but that clashes with the second case above.

To disambiguate, we need a quote.

```
'(Bool, Int) :: (Type, Type)  -- term-at-type::kind
-- Now it kind-checks
```

The syntax for lists has similar issues:

```
[x] :: [Bool]      -- term::type
[Bool] :: Type     -- type::kind
```

But what if we want a singleton list of types? The syntax would be:

```
[Bool] :: [Type]   -- term-at-type::kind
-- This is a kind error!
```

but that clashes again. We need a quote, again:

```
'[Bool] :: [Type]   -- term-at-type::kind
-- Now this kind-checks
```

We do get other ambiguities in a few other cases:

```
[] :: Type -> Type
[] :: [Type]   -- wanted, but clashes
'[] :: [Type]  -- OK

data T :: T
T :: Type
T :: T     -- clashes
'T :: T    -- OK
```

It is best if we always add quotes.

Comment: Richard Eisenberg has said that he thinks the warning was a mistake.

Comment: The only thing that remains unclear to me is why `["A", "B"]` was accepted...

Comment: @dfeuer I see -- I removed that part.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The syntax `[x]` is ambiguous since it can mean `x : []` or `[] x` (e.g., `[Int] = [] Int`). The syntax `[x,y]` can only mean `x : y : []`, so it is not ambiguous.